# ASP.Net Session clearing between postbacks?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

This popped up today and is very strange.  We cannot figure out what changed but it was working before.

Essentially we have a class called "ProjectSession" that holds static properties and methods to do with the session.
The main one is `ProjectSession.ProjectId` which is nothing but a wrapper for `HttpContext.Current.Session["ProjectID"]`.  When a new project is created, we set the ID in this property.  If the user already has a project we set the value on Page Load `if (!IsPostBack)`.  Pretty simple.

However, halfway through the day today we suddenly started seeing this value disappear from the session.  In fact the entire session object is clearing out.  On the first page of the site, we set the value if the user has a project.  Then on the very first Button click, we check the value and it's null.

Every piece of code we have worked on today does not seem to affect this and in fact everything works fine on our production server, just not on our local machines.

If anyone has any ideas what could cause this please let me know.

p.s. --> We have double, triple and quadruple checked.  There are 0 lines of code that says `ProjectSession =` and exactly 2 lines of code that say `ProjectSession.ProjectID =` and those are the 2 I mentioned in this question.

Comment: Are you running multiple w3wp processes? If so, are you using a state server or a database to hold the sessions?

Comment: app pools can recycle.  is it possible it recycled?

Comment: On our local machines it is just using the default "Cassinni" server (I believe that is what it is called, the one that Visual Studio launches automatically) so I don't think either of those situations apply

Comment: I would turn on ASP.NET health monitoring and ensure that the "application start" and "application shutdown" events are logged. That way you can tell if/when your application is restarting. EDIT : Can the problem be reproduced locally if you use IIS instead of Cassini ?

Answer (score 2):

Cassinni will reset the "app pool"(it's not the same as IIS) all the time.  You should do your testing in an environment as close to production as you can.  At the bare minimum I suggest you use IIS if it's a critical bug you are trying to solve and reproduce.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that someone added this line to our Web.Config file:
`<httpCookies domain="THEPUBLICSITE" />`

So the server thought when we worked locally that we were trying to do Cross Site Scripting (XSS).